# ionic2: run IOS error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and i have installed Xcode. When i run command `ionic cordova run ios` in my ionic project directory i get this error:

```
Cordova encountered an error.
You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova prepare (exit code 1):


You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova
telemetry on.
Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-android is
deprecated. Upgrade to cordova-android@5.0.0 or newer.
Error: Your android platform does not have Api.js

macbooks-mbp:canon macbookpro$ (node:839) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: channel closed
```

I didn't install android studio nor it's sdk, as i want to run the project in ios emulator. Can any one tell me the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of cordova-android are you using? have you tried to update as suggested?

Comment: And if that doesn't work, try 'cordova telemetry off'

Comment: what does `cordova requirements` command output?

Comment: @HelderDeBaere I have already tried cordova telemetry off I got You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on. and then have the same error of run iOS

Comment: @peval27 the same error

Comment: @suraj that's what  had:Error: Your android platform does not have Api.js

Comment: try re installing the platform

Comment: @suraj I have already tried and the same output

Comment: try removing all platforms and add ios platform

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas now I get this error Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: In your project folder root, do cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas It Works Thank you

Comment: @Al-shimaaAdel Happy coding